# Apache MetaModel select by id from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-metamodel

I am validating Apache MetaModel as a storage abstraction layer and experienced problem with primary key lookup in MongoDB.

As we know every document in mongo has unique `_id` column with `ROWID` type, and using metamodel I can't even to run query "select by id"

This query return no data, but I am 100% sure document with this id in collection:

```
DataSet ds = dc.query()
            .from("users")
            .selectAll()
            .where("_id").eq("56334c6fb38cfec169db2ccb")
            .execute();
```

Using 'id' as a pkey throws obvious "Could not find column: id"

```
DataSet ds = dc.query()
            .from("users")
            .selectAll()
            .where("id").eq("56334c6fb38cfec169db2ccb")
            .execute();
```

Filtering on other columns works fine. 
I have a gut feeling I am doing something wrong, could someone advise  suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. I have reported an issue in MetaModel's JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/METAMODEL-211

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix it locally for now. But what do you think we can get a released public version for MetaModel with fix, assuming we have the fix?

Comment: I cannot promise an immediate release, but Apache MetaModel is released regularly, so after merging a pull request, the fix will be soon publicly available.